# How to return 400 response using the same format that Asp.Net Core validation uses?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, http-status-code-400, model-validation

I use model validation in Asp.Net Core and it returns 400 errors like that:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "MyProperty": [
            "Error 1",
            "Error 2"
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "0HLRTF1TPCO60:00000002"
}
```

I do have my custom validation that does not use Asp.Net core built-in mechanisms, but I'd like to generate the error in exact same format so that it would be easier for users to consume. I can of course just generate JSON myself, but I think there is some built-in API to generate such an error from model, though I cannot manage to find what should I call.

P.S. I want to do this in middleware

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out myself how this can be achieved:

```
var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
modelState.AddModelError("FieldName", "ErrorMessage");
var details = new ValidationProblemDetails(modelState);
details.Status = (int?) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
details.Extensions["traceId"] = context.TraceIdentifier;
```

The details can later be serialized to JSON.